# true or false : is $2^n = Ω(3^n) $

Tags: asymptotics

$2^n = Ω(3^n) $

let $n= 0$

then

$1<1*c$ for any $c>1$

so my answer is yes, but the textbook answer implies I am wrong.
may I know where I am doing it wrongly?

Comment: Your error is looking at $n=0$

Comment: so I am assuming I have to use $n>= 0$ if I am doing it this way without limit?

Comment: Is the statement "$2^n = \Omega(3^n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$" or...?

Comment: @smcc I suppose it's "$2^n=\Omega(3^n)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$" (see [big omega notation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-omega-notation))

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have looked at the tag. I was thinking of another use of the notation $\Omega(m)$ (number of prime factors of $m$).

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{2^n}{3^n}=\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n$.

Suppose this were were greater than some positive $k$ for an infinite number of  positive integers $n$. Then taking logs, $n \lt -\dfrac{\log(k)}{\log(3/2)}$  for an infinite number of positive integers $n$.  But that is false, as only a finite number of positive integers can be less than any given number.

So $2^n \not = \Omega(3^n)$